# Keeping a constant number to a set, before it appends other numbers

Tags: python-2.7, function, loops

I have a set of numbers which is generated real-time during running the code.  In the snippet of code shown below with the function `constant_set`, the number generated real time are stored in the variable `set_accepted_list_frozen`. What i want to ask is, if i want to keep a constant number always in the `set_accepted_list_frozen` before the other numbers are appended to the list `set_accepted_list_frozen`, how should i proceed?

```
set_accepted_list_frozen = set()
def constant_set(set_accepted_list,set_forbidden_list):
    global set_accepted_list_frozen
    if num_accepted >= len(set_accepted_list_frozen): 
        for var in set_accepted_list:
            if len(set_accepted_list_frozen) == num_accepted:
                break
            set_accepted_list_frozen.add(var)
```

Comment: You can't have a mutable frozenset.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I am appending the elements to a null set. What i was asking is if want a specific element to be present in the set_accepted_list_frozen as default number, what i have to do?

Comment: `set_accepted_list_frozen = { your_number_here }` Is this what you want?